# Слеш команды Discord Python

Tags: python, discord, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Есть проблема , хочу добавить в бота в дискорд слеш команды пишу на Python .

При попытке задействования библиотек таким кодом:

```
**import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option**
```

[image: То есть , тупо отсутствуют нужные мне библиотеки]
Я загружал либы такие как

```
pip install discord.py
pip install discord-py-slash-command
```

Везде пишут что нужно просто их поставить и все будет работать , но нет , вообще не пашет перепробовал тучу просто библиотек разных , даже в разных IDE пробовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загрузите либу disnake `pip install disnake` и импортируйте

```
import disnake
from disnake.enums import ButtonStyle
```

Библиотека на 100% аналогична дискорд пай, только вместо discord.xxx используется disnake.xxx